# Is a grammar that accepts function declarations, function calls and expressions (at any order!) necessarily cyclic?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, ambiguity

As the title suggests, assume a grammar which has to recognize function declarations, function calls, and expressions, at *any order*. Does that mean it has to be cyclic, and therefore ambiguous?

I mean, it would have to look something like:

- S -> function_declaration | function_call | expr
- function_declaration -> ... | S
- function_call -> ... | S
- expr -> ... | S

Maybe not all of them would have to point back to S, that depends on the specifics.
Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Define "cyclic" please?  I don't see why "cyclic" implies _ambiguous_.  I don't think Lisp is ambiguous.

Comment: Assume *A -> B | a* and *B -> A | b*. There are two derivations for a. One is A => a, one is A => B => A => a. So it's ambiguous.

Comment: ... which (by simple substitution) is equivalent to `A -> A | b | a`, which is not ambiguous.  Okay.  Why did I assume that?  (And what does that assumption have to do with giving a concrete definition of "cyclic"?)

Comment: But what you just wrote is in fact ambiguous.

Comment: A => a, or A => A => a.

Comment: Easily fixed.  `A -> aA | bA | a | b`.  You are still evading the thing that you need to do to make your question meaningful.  Define "cyclic".

Comment: Any "non-cyclic" (I assume you mean $A \Rightarrow^* xAy$ for some non-terminal $A$) grammar defines a finite language. Go figure.

Comment: But this new grammar accepts different strings than the initial one, so it's not equivalent. The first one could not accept aa, but yours can. A context-free grammar is cyclic if there exists a non-terminal A and a derivation in one or more steps A => ... => A.

Comment: @Raphael so a grammar being cyclic doesn't also make it ambiguous?

Comment: Not at all. $S \to aS \mid \varepsilon$ is "cyclic" but clearly an unambiguous grammar (for $a^*$). The two concepts are simply unrelated (which is quite apparent from the definition of ambiguity),

Comment: That made sense... thanks Raphael! And thank you also, Wandering Logic, for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is just no need for rules (or non-terminals) that are cyclic,
which I understand means that, for some non-terminal $X$, you have 
$X\stackrel*\Rightarrow X$.

What you often need is recursive rules and non-terminals, such that
$X\stackrel*\Rightarrow uXv$, where $u$ and $v$ are strings of
symbols. Without them, the language is finite.

For example, in the case of expressions you may have:

- $Expr \to Term + Expr \mid Term$
- $Term \to Factor * Term \mid Factor$
- $Factor \to Ident \mid Literal \mid ( Expr )$

This said, you are right that cyclicity, as you define it, does make
the grammar ambiguous iff the cyclic symbol can also derive on a
terminal string.

Comment: I see... I think recursion is the way to go in my problem! Thank you once more!